# Gluon Mobile JavaFxPorts App Store Release

Tags: gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

Which task must be used to build an os app with the distribution signing key? I tried to upload my current .ipa file and the application loader told me that it was signed with a "Development Loader". How do I configure the .ipa file to be signed by my distribution signing key?

Comment: Are you using a provisioning profile for production?

Comment: Yes, it is a distribution provisioning profile but whenever the "ios" or "createIpa" tasks run, they search for provisioning profiles that begin with the work "Development" rather than "Distribution"

Comment: Do you use `iosSignIdentity` and `iosProvisioningProfile` in your build.gradle file?

Comment: I used one of each at a time, but when I did they displayed the message "could not find". Do I have to use both at the same time?

Comment: Yes, you need both. But in order to use them, you need to have the proper values... that you should find using XCode->Preferences->Accounts->View Details.

Comment: Which value is supposed to be used for "iosprovisioningprofile"?

Comment: Just the name you see on (XCode) View Details. Make sure you have downloaded that provisioning profile (the Download button is not visible).